# Powerlines and internet speed

Tags: home-networking

I have several powerlines from tp-link in my house. According to the data speeds I see in each of them they seem to be communicatIng well with each other. In general, the speed is always above 100mbps, and most of the time well above that. 
I have a nvidia shield connected by cable to one of this powerlines and when I measure my internet speed I usually get 30/40 mbps (tho sometimes it lowers to 10mbps). But if I connect it directly to my router I get the real internet speed I have, 100/120mbps.

If I understand correctly, if my powerlines connect between them at a speed of at least 100mbps, that's like using a cable. So why is my internet speed a lot slower than using the direct cable? What am I missing here?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvzJk.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Py1fN.jpg

Comment: Make and model of the Powerline Adapters and the Router may help shed some light so give us that detail. The make and the model of the adapters and of the direct connect router when you measure.

Comment: You may need line noise filters on both ends.  In addition, filters on electrical noisy things like frigs and microwaves could also help.

Comment: Overall speed is governed not just by throughput but also by latency. Perhaps the powerline adapters have good throughput but bad latency.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using more than two powerline devices is that (like WiFi)  you are going to be limited to a half-duplex signal with collisions due to the fact that all data signals are on the same piece of wire.

Half-duplex means that every powerline device must be in either receiving mode or transmitting mode. You cannot transmit data on one wire while receiving on the other. With standard Ethernet there are separate pairs of wire for transmit and receive signals, this means that Ethernet can be very efficient and acknowledge one packet of data while receiving another, powerline systems must wait for data to finish being received before sending an acknowledge back which could make the overall system slower and less effective.

As multiple devices are sharing a single set of wires (your house wiring) for sending data you also have the problem of "collisions". This is where multiple devices try to send data at the same time and effectively end up shouting over each other and corrupting the actual data being transmitted by both senders. Receivers cannot work out what was being sent by either sender and the block of data from each sender has to be stopped and retransmitted, this time hopefully not at the same time. Most devices try not to collide by watching for "quiet" time on the data line, but eventually they will transmit data and if another device tries at the same time then a collision will occur and a brief period of time is lost while each device back off and tries to retransmit.

Modern Ethernet does not have either of these problems. The ethernet in your router will be "switched" by an intelligent controller, meaning that data is not simply retransmitted on every output but is only output on ports where it is needed. The separate transmit and receive lines combined with this controller effectively removes the likelihood of data collisions.

Because of these problems the best case is going to be having only two power line adaptors which will limit collisions. Having "several" will just make the problems progressively worse and amplify the effect of collisions and reduce your effective bandwidth, especially when multiple devices are trying to send data at the same time.

Ethernet is going to be a lot more efficient than a powerline adaptor and is going to use the available bandwidth more effectively.